# Java - H2 Database - getGeneratedKeys() not returning any results

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc, h2

Ok, what am I missing?

I have a table as such:

```
CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.RESULTS
(RESULTID IDENTITY NOT NULL,
SOURCEID INTEGER NOT NULL,
PARENTID INTEGER,
NAME VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
VALUE CLOB NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (RESULTID))
```

I've tried having RESULTID both be a INTEGER with AUTO_INCREMENT and as a type IDENTITY.

I'm using prepared statements, and no mater what I do, I keep throwing a "no data" exception when trying to set the value of a:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO RESULTS (SOURCEID, PARENTID, NAME, VALUE) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement stmt = null;
stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
... {Truncated setting of values} ...

stmt.executeUpdate();
conn.commit();
ResultSet rs2 = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
rs2.next();
Integer a = rs2.getInt(1);
```

When I actually look in the database, the data is inserted properly, with the next value set for the RESULTID field just fine, I just can't seem to return the value.

I have to be doing something silly, since this should work. Any ideas?

Since someone asked the full stack trace is below:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: No data is available [2000-170]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:146)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:135)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcResultSet.checkOnValidRow(JdbcResultSet.java:2957)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcResultSet.get(JdbcResultSet.java:2963)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcResultSet.getInt(JdbcResultSet.java:307)
    at com.cigital.db.DefaultDb.storeValue(DefaultDb.java:147)
    at com.cigital.db.DefaultDb.processResult(DefaultDb.java:115)
    at com.cigital.db.DefaultDb.importScan(DefaultDb.java:84)
    at com.cigital.gui.Default.jButImportActionPerformed(Default.java:373)
    at com.cigital.gui.Default.access$400(Default.java:26)
    at com.cigital.gui.Default$6.actionPerformed(Default.java:131)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:272)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6289)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6054)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4652)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4482)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4577)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4238)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4482)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:644)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:85)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:603)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:601)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:617)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:615)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:614)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Comment: Have you tried getting the generated key before committing the connection? WHat's the complete stack trace of the exception?

Comment: Added the stack trace to the post...

Comment: I just reread your post and realized you recommended I pulled the keys before doing the commit. I went back and changed that in the code, and sure enough it works! That seems weird to me... If you want to post it as an actual answer, I can accept it...

Comment: Done that. I don't have an explanation or documentation reference. It just seemed more logical to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to get the generated keys *before* committing the connection, and not after.